# How to verify sideloaded APKs?

Tags: google-play-store, apk, side-loading, authentication

I have sideloaded APKs, which are not available on sites like [APK Mirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/) or [APK Pure](https://apkpure.com/), from Google Play via the [Evozi APK downloading service](https://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/). It is an online banking app, so I want to verify it. How can this be done? I get checksums by uploading the files to [Virus Total](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload):

[image]

How can I get the checksums of the authentic APKs?

NOTE: I do not have a Google account.